# How do I check the type of an object which might not be the instance of a specified class?

Tags: java

This code is trying to check the type of an object.

```
class Animal{}
class Cat extends Animal{}
class Dog extends Animal{}
class InheritanceXP{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Dog adog = new Dog();
        System.out.println(adog instanceof Animal);
        System.out.println(adog instanceof Dog);
        try{
            System.out.println(adog instanceof Cat);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

two of them, `adog instanceof Animal` and `adog instanceof Dog` works well though, the last one,  `adog instanceof Cat` keeps throwing `incompatible types` error during compilation, even I put it in `try` block.

How do I do?

Comment: `adog` is not an instance of `Cat`, although they share the same superclass.

Comment: So, it will keep throwing `incompatible types`.

Comment: Please, take a look here: https://www.journaldev.com/644/inheritance-java-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`try / catch` is a runtime construct. It's something you do when a block of code might throw an exception *while it's running*.

`Dog adog = new Dog();` is a compile time construct. It explicitly tells the compiler that the type is `Dog` which has no relation to `Cat`, so it doesn't have to wait to run the app to know it's not going to work.

If you want your block of code to work, change the *declared* type to `Animal`.
`Animal adog = new Dog();` If the *declared* type is `Animal` then it's possible for it to be `Cat` at runtime and your code will compile.